# SQL server select all columns in the database except a specified name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I tried the following SQL statement but still received output columns with the name I wanted to exclude. What am I doing wrong here?

```
DECLARE @SQL AS VarChar(MAX)
SET @SQL = ''

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'SELECT * FROM ' + A.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.[' + A.TABLE_NAME + ']' + CHAR(13)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS A JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns AS B ON A.TABLE_NAME = B.TABLE_NAME
WHERE column_name NOT IN ('rowstamp')

EXEC (@SQL)
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM`, this is wrong\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not keep `*`. Try this instead

```
DECLARE @SQL AS VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL = ''

SELECT @sql += 'SELECT ' + column_name + ' from '
               + A.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.[' + A.TABLE_NAME + ']'
               + Char(13)
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS A
       JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns AS B
         ON A.TABLE_NAME = B.TABLE_NAME
WHERE  column_name NOT IN ( 'rowstamp' )

EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: @Tarek Merachli, this will produce as much selects as there are columns in table. For example:  `Select Col1 From Table1, Select Col2 From Table1`. This will not produce selects `Select Col1, Col2 From Table1`. Did you want this behaiviour? If yes you better correct your question for others to understand you correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @SQL AS VarChar(MAX)
SET @SQL = ''

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'SELECT ' + c.Columns + ' FROM '  + A.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.[' + A.TABLE_NAME + ']' +  CHAR(13) 

FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS A

CROSS APPLY (SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Column_Name) 
             FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns B WHERE A.TABLE_NAME = B.TABLE_NAME AND B.column_name NOT IN ('rowstamp')
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'') AS Columns) c

PRINT     @SQL
```